# CLion Can't Find File

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream, clion

When using CLion 2016.2.3 I can't seem to locate a file even when I don't use relative directories. When compiling a programming using g++ it works perfectly but fails with CLion leading me to believe that this is an issue with CLion.. Any suggestions?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    ifstream file("C:\Users\Mackenzie\Desktop\Parser\test.asm");

    // segmentation fault at line above.. can't find file

    ifstream file("C:/Users/Mackenzie/Desktop/Parser/test.asm");

    // even with normal slashes this won't work

    // using relative directory ex "test.asm" also doesn't work

    return 0

}
```

CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Parser)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES parser.cpp)
add_executable(Parser ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x774d636d in ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

Comment: Please post your exact error.

Comment: @BadZen added the error

Comment: Also for starters you need to escape your backslashes in double-quoted C strings.

Comment: time to fire up your debugger and find out what is going wrong...